# performance impact of long list of catch c++

Tags: c++11, exception

I want to create a method that can tell me if an exception is retry-able or not. Exceptions are from 3rd party library. So i have something like this :

```
bool isRetryable ( std::exception_ptr ex) {
    try {
        if(ex) {
            std::rethrow_exception (ex);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (const ExceptionA& ex) {
        return true;
    } catch (const ExceptionB& ex) {
        return true;
    } catch (const ExceptionC& ex) {
        return true;
    } catch (const ExceptionD& ex) {
        return false;
    } catch (const ExceptionE& ex) {
        return false;
    } catch (const ExceptionF& ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The list of Exceptions can go as long as 100, So my question is - what is the impact of a long list of exception and is there any other way to accomplish the same goal ?

Comment: I mean you can try measuring yourself. If the exceptions have a common base you can try dynamic_casts: but if they are faster you have to measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the C++ runtime library, but in general having a long list of catch blocks will result in O(n) performance as the implementation performs a linear scan, matching the thrown exception type against each of the types in the list of catch blocks in turn; this is e.g. how libstdc++ (the default C++ runtime on Linux) works.

I don't know whether any other runtime libraries optimize this, but I'd suspect they wouldn't, as a long list of exception blocks would usually be considered a "code smell" and also since the implementation is required to ensure that the first matching catch block receives the exception, which makes a linear scan the natural implementation.

However, if all your exceptions derive from a polymorphic base (e.g. `std::exception`) there is a much more elegant solution: you can take the `typeid` of the exception, construct a `std::type_index` and look it up in a container:

```
struct ExceptionA : std::exception {};
// etc.

static std::unordered_set<std::type_index> const retryables{
  typeid(ExceptionA),
  typeid(ExceptionB),
  typeid(ExceptionC)
};

bool isRetryable ( std::exception_ptr ex) {
    try {
        if(ex) {
            std::rethrow_exception (ex);
        }
        return true;
    } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        return retryables.count(typeid(ex));
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/959463aae11263bc)</kbd>.

Comment: nice answer but maybe still point out the idea of having 100 exceptions and catching them all in one single place probably indicates design problems